# not ready getElementById

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, parseint

When I am entering a number into the input, the result is coming back as NaN, even I parseInt the result. I also tried with a string and it is not reading it either.

Please advise on why it is not reading the input.

Thank you,
Avi

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Validation</h2>

<p>Please input a number between 1 and 10:</p>

<input id="numb">

<button type="button" id="mult">Submit</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var first = parseInt(document.getElementById('numb').value, 10);

document.getElementById('mult').addEventListener('click', multiply);

function multiply() {
    console.log(first);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `first` inside your `multiply()` function

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Validation</h2>

<p>Please input a number between 1 and 10:</p>

<input id="numb">

<button type="button" id="mult">Submit</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

document.getElementById('mult').addEventListener('click', multiply);

function multiply() {
   var first = parseInt(document.getElementById('numb').value, 10);
   console.log(first);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. why did it not work when i defined the variable first outside the function? By declaring the variable outside the function, doe the function not have access to it?